# Matrix calculations in SIMPLERNN KERAS

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to understand the Matrix Calculations involved in SIMPLERNN.

I have understood from some blog posts and stackoverflow that SimpleRNN(units) creates a layer where in each layer contains no.of units of RNN.
SimpleRNN involves the following calculations

W = kernel #shape-(1,units)

U = recurrent_kernel #shape-(units,units)

B = bias #shape -(units,)

output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)

Help me understand what are the input and output dimensions of the following below code snippet.

Function for generating X and Y. Where Y is the Cummulative sum of X.

'def generate_batch(n=256):

```
X = np.random.choice(a=[0, 1], size = n*seq_len, p=[0.9, 0.1]).reshape(n, -1)

y = np.cumsum(X, axis=1)

X = X.reshape(n, -1, 1)

y = y.reshape(n, -1, 1)

return(X, y) #returns shape X,y-(256,60,1)
```

model = Sequential()

model.add(SimpleRNN(10, input_shape=(60, 1), return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

X, y = generate_batch()#(256,60,1)

model.fit(X, y, verbose=0, epochs=1)'

please help me figure out the dimensions of input to RNN ,state and output dimension from RNN.How does the matrix calculations occur i.e (W * input + U * state + B).